# Fill a container with given boxes

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have a problem in Algorithms Class which i am trying to solve for the past two days but I can't. I want to fully fill a container with the MINIMUM number of given boxes with dynamic programming. My container has a certain size and I have different box sizes AND quantities of them (so i have 24 boxes of size 20, 15 boxes of size 48 etc). I think that i gotta somehow modify the knapsack problem? But the knapsack is not necessarily fully filled whilst in my problem i have to fill the container completely. Also I gotta somehow connect the hypothetical value of the knapsack with the sizes of the boxes. Any hints?

Comment: Is this like a rigid container of some given dimensions that must be filled exactly with some boxes of other dimensions, like packing a moving van to capacity? Or is this more like filling an expandable container like a knapsack which has a maximum volume?